# My SumIfs returns zero with 1 different criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

What I want to do is to compare summary of two sets of data within periods of time in large timeline.

I just don't understand why my SumIfs returns zero when I change 1 criteria.

First:

```
=SUMIFS($D38:$MW38;$D$6:$MW$6;">"&NI$9-7;$D$6:$MW$6;"<="&NI$9;$D$7:$MW$7;$NB$7)*$MZ38
```

Second:

```
=SUMIFS($D38:$MW38;$D$6:$MW$6;">"&PK$9-7;$D$6:$MW$6;"<="&PK$9;$D$7:$MW$7;$NC$7)*$MZ38
```

The difference is only at `$NB$7` and `$NC$7`. Both are not empty.

This Formula is supposed to be date criteria range

```
">"&NI$9-7;$D$6:$MW$6;"<="&NI$9;$D$7:$MW$7
```

The first code outputs value, but the second didn't.

I don't know what to do at this point.

**Data set**

[image: data set]

**Output 1**

[image: output 1]

**Output 2**

[image: output 2]

Comment: Post few sample data for better understanding.

Comment: my range stretch horizontally, not vertically. so the lines stays constant, but the letter stretch from D to MW, which is the same.

Comment: @Harun24HR there is nothing inherently wrong with the ranges in the OPs formula.

Comment: @Musa without sample data, and your expected results, this can't be answered (and will probably be closed).  Please add thagt information by editing it into your question.  Add the sample data as text so we can copy it.

Comment: @Musa posting sample data **as an image** is not useful.  I, for one, am not going to retype it when you could include it as text.  And leaving out the row and column headers just makes us guess how the data relates to your formula

Comment: im sorry im new to this, i added my screenshot to make a bit clear?

Comment: can i attach my file in this?

Comment: @Musa few people are going to download a file from a random stranger.  I know I'm not going to.

Comment: "This Formula is supposed to be date criteria range" <-- try to feed (exactly) the same value in botch cell.. see if the result is the same. | Check also the cells formatting (should be date formatted for both)..

Comment: You could also try to use **Evaluate** in the **Formulas** tab to see where it throws a false.  Also, I may not have followed the logic closely, but you said that you only changed $NB$7 and $NC$7.  What about the change of NI$9 to PK$9?

Comment: @p._phidot_ yes, all conditions are all same, even same sizing cells.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick the change is the location of the date cells as you can see in the image output 1 and 2, i even tried  change the date format, doesn't effect anything.

Comment: actually found the problem. two merged cells as you can see in my data set header reads as one have value, and the second reads blank. this makes my date criteria had no value when it should have. i had to write everything from scratch to find this. thanks guys.

Comment: glad it helps (in the troubleshooting).. / (^-^)